# Brightness on bootcamp is totally off

Tags: bootcamp, windows, display

So i have a MBP retina 15" that has a Windows 7 Bootcamp partition.
The other day I noticed my screen was a little dirty so I took the screen brightness all the way down (<kbd>fn</kbd>+ <kbd>f1</kbd>) and did this while Windows 7 was locked.
I now cannot get the brightness back up.

I have hard booted and it seems to get back to the Windows 7 login screen.  I'm not 100% sure if it's there but if I press <kbd>esc</kbd>, I can hear the Windows *ting* error sound.  So it seems that i am there.

Is there any way to "reset" the brightness for bootcamp?

Answer (score 1):

just had the same issue.
Here are some Options:

- you are connected to local LAN and able to log on remotely and can find the registry setting or slider in energy options
- you connect a 2nd external monitor and with some luck it shows at least some Desktop
- you reinstall windows :(
- Use Safe Mode
- Use Safe Mode to remove the password for the account and allow automatic login.  From there you can try running some commands to change the brightness, or hope the Fn keys work after logging in automatically.